# Create chart in webview using google charts

Tags: java, android, charts, google-visualization

I have an application in which I want to create a chart like this:

[image: Chart sample]

**I want to generate a chart as it is in a webview in my activity using google charts**. In what way can I do this?

**Sample [url](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chd=t:40,60,60,45,47,75,70,72&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7C0%7C20%7C30%7C40%7C50%7C60%7C70%7C80%7C90%7C10%7C1:%7C0%7C25%7C50%7C75%7C100&chs=200x125) of a chart**

P.S.: I can directly open the url in a webview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try achartengine but it does not display charts in webview

Comment: can you show me a tutorial or sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an alternative to google chart wizard, you can use achartengine.

http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html.

Tutorials are available at

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2603F3CABBF5EEB0.

List if links that can help learn achartengine

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2603F3CABBF5EEB0

http://android-sample-code.blogspot.in/2012/06/draw-charts-in-application-using.html

http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/